# Slide from side to side

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-animate, mouseover

I'm using jquery to slide a div containing thumbnails from left to right. The functions bellow works, but they will only move 30px each time the mouse rolls over the arrow. Is there a way to move say 30px a second the whole time the mouse is over the arrow, then once the mouse is moved, the animation stops?

```
$(".left-arrow").mouseover(function(){
 $("#slides").animate({ 
    left: "-=30px",
  }, 1000 );
}); 

$(".right-arrow").mouseover(function(){
 $("#slides").animate({ 
    left: "+=30px",
  }, 1000 );
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main logic is to use the callback function of [animate()](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) to relaunch animation when finished  :

```
$(".left-arrow").mouseover(function(){
  playanim("+=30px");
}).mouseleave(function(){
  stopanim();
}); 

$(".right-arrow").mouseover(function(){
  playanim("-=30px");
}).mouseleave(function(){
  stopanim();
}); 

function playanim(speed)
{
  // launch the anim with the desired side
  $("#slides").animate({ 
    left: speed,
  }, 1000,'linear',function(){playanim(speed);});
}

function stopanim()
{
  // stop the animation and clear the animation queue
  $("#slides").stop(true);
}
```

It should work :)

Here is a Jiddle to check : [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/A2eKq/1/)

EDIT : To add constraint to your sliding, the quick way can be performed by testing the left position of the slide.
Look at this [Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/A2eKq/4/) for a quick sample with min/max constraint

Comment: Awesome, works perfectly! One more question, how would I set a limit on how far the div can travel from the left and to the right? IE: left arrow wont allow #slides to move any farther than 0;

Comment: You should add a test that constraint the position of the slide in playanim(). I update the code